# Why do some people require shaking Arba Minim (four species) in the Succah?

Tags: sukkah, water, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Related (but not a duplicate of) the old [question here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76932/why-is-the-mitzvah-of-the-four-species-especially-appropriate-for-the-holiday-of?newreg=b997dbdddd5a41e29e667ef63ebd5542) inquiring the logical connection between Arba Minim and the holiday of Succot.

My question is in a slightly different vein - if the Arba Minim symbolizes the water libation that took place in the Temple, and is therefore thematically valid for the same timeframe, but *not* related to the Succah itself (which were to commemorate the divine clouds in the desert after the exodus), why do some prefer/require to fulfill the Mitzvah of Arba Minim in the Succah?

Comment: closely related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117805/whats-the-reason-behind-the-minhag-of-shaking-the-lulav-in-the-sukkah

Comment: Maybe they don't accept your premise that they aren't related? Do you have some reason to think people who accept your premise also insist on this joint performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the reason behind the minhag of shaking the lulav in the sukkah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117805/whats-the-reason-behind-the-minhag-of-shaking-the-lulav-in-the-sukkah)

Comment: I admit I did not actually see that question in my search. However, is there any reason shaking the Lulav would normally be preferred to be done in the house, rather than where ever you are? @Alex, your answer solves why shaking in the Succah is preferred over your own home, but not sure it discusses why Mitzvos need to be done in the person's residence (although it would be great if there's some source for that to complete the puzzle).

Comment: @DoubleAA - I have not found a reason why the Arba Minim is connected to the holiday of Succot and exodus (much to my dismay). Is there a reason they would be related?